# Why doesn't NULL pointer work?

Tags: c++, null

here's my code

```
class LList{
struct Elem{int data;Elem *next;};     
Elem *head;
public:


void Push(int dat){
  if(head==NULL){
    head=new Elem;
    head->data=dat;
    head->next=NULL;
  } else {
    // ......
  }
}
```

But when i use it, it doesn't work. The problem is it never finds the pointer to be NULL and it should me NULL. Even when I assigning NULL to the pointer in constructor it doesn't work.  Visual Studio gives me error that says I cannot access desired memory location.

Comment: Please add some line-breaks to your example code.

Comment: Do you need to dereference `head`, e.g. `*head` when you access it?

Comment: "Why doesn't X work" is the wrong question. The right question would be "where is my error in trying to make X work". You're not allowed to presume that X does in fact not work until you understand it completely.

Comment: I am not here to read someone's philosophy. I asked for help. If you don't want to help, don't comment then.

Comment: @Misha: `calloc`?  Not in C++...

Comment: It is certainly possible to calloc in C++ (it merely requires and explicit cast). For some reason NULL is not actually NULL which means that the memory it lies on might not actually be zeroed (for some terrible terrible reason).

Comment: @Irrational: Don't be harsh on people that are actually trying to help you. You may not like some comments, but more than often, people look for a solution in the wrong places or assume the problem is not in their way of doing things. If you are not open to criticism, don't ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply initialize `head` in the ctor and it should work.

```
class LList{
  //...
  LList() : head(0) {} // or head(NULL) if you prefer
  // ...
};
```

**Note:** IIRC it is considered equally bad style comparing with `== NULL` as for example `== TRUE` ... the better (in my not so humble opinion) style is `if(!head)`, but that is cosmetics. So just a note.

Comment: He already said that initializing `head` in the constructor didn't fix it.

Comment: @VeeArr: but he didn't show the ctor and there is a good chance that something else in the ctor interfered if s/he was not using the initializer list of the ctor, but instead assigned (as the text implied) inside the ctor's body. Quite a difference, IMO.